# Unable to access array data in model Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create array (i.e. $userInfo) in controller and I want this data in model to fire some query. But this data cant be retrieve. i tried many ways for this. Please help me regarding this issue.

Below method does not work for me.

```
echo element('email', $userInfo);
print_r($userInfo->email);
print_r($userInfo[0][email]);
foreach ($userInfo as $res){print_r($res->email);}
```

I create array in controller using

```
$userInfo = array('email'=>$email, 'roleId'=>$roleId, 'name'=>$name,'mobile'=>$mobile, 'updatedBy'=>$this->vendorId, 'updatedDtm'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

My model function is below

```
function editUser($userInfo, $userId)
    {
        print_r(json_encode($userInfo));

        echo element('email', $userInfo);

        foreach ($userInfo as $res)
        {
            print_r($res->email);                    

        }

        print_r(temp[0]["email"]);    
        exit(0);
        return false;
    }
```

This is the result of print_r(json_encode($userInfo));

```
{"email":"patilsumit@gmail.com","roleId":"4","name":"Sumit Patil","mobile":"+918007840200","updatedBy":"1","updatedDtm":"2019-07-31 06:39:02"}
```

I want access email, roleId, name etc values in model.

Comment: How are you calling Model Method from Controller?

Comment: call your model method in controller

Comment: by using $result = $this->user_model->editUser($userInfo, $userId);

Answer (score 0):

try this:
//controller

```
$userInfo = array('email'=>$email, 'roleId'=>$roleId, 'name'=>$name,'mobile'=>$mobile, 'updatedBy'=>$this->vendorId, 'updatedDtm'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$this->load->model('model_name');
$result=$this->model_name->editUser($userInfo,$userId);
```